# Why this Django signal not triggered?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, signals

I have an app called aaa.

Inside "aaa.models" there are some models

Inside "aaa.signals" there is a function which looks like this

```
@receiver(pre_save)
def generate_thumbnail(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print("get called")
```

Inside "aaa.apps.py", there is something like this, which is waking up the signal function.

```
class AaaConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'aaa'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

I have included this app into "settings.py"

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...... ,
    'aaa',
]
```

#### I have found that this signal never gets called when any of the models' instance is saved,

#### no matter the instance is saved during test or shell, or normal running time.

Answer (score 0):

The INSTALLED_APPS should include `aaa.apps.AaaConfig`  not `aaa`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        ...... ,
        'aaa.apps.AaaConfig',
    ]
```

Comment: this solution consumess me tons of time to find out.